# Why a company files multiple S-1 (IPO)

Tags: united-states, shares, ipo, sec, electronic-filing

I have noticed companies file multiple s-1 and s-1/a

What is the difference between s-1 and s-1/a when both are being used to file IPO. And why a company files multiple s-1 / s-1/a forms. Isn't that suppose to be done only once at the time of going to public first?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An S-1 is the initial registration statement, S-1/a is an amended statement. There are typically one or more of these before the SEC has no further questions and the company can proceed to declare the registration "effective." This is because a company does not go public just by filing a registration statement. The SEC has a period of time to comment on it and standard practice is for companies to file S-1's and subsequent S-1/a's until the SEC is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It is very helpful information. I have came through a news that a company going for IPO ( Cemtrex Inc). When I checked, the company filed s-1 on Aug 2016 and is being traded from last 4 years. How could it be possible?

Comment: A registration statement (S-1 - there are others for special cases) is issued when a company proposes to sell securities in a new public offering. It's not only for an IPO.  Companies need to have a registration whenever they wish to issue new securities. There are special flavors of these for ongoing issuance, for instance, to provide employee stock option exercises. If you read the filing it will explain things in excruciating detail.  https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1435064/000114420416121822/v447892_s1.htm